# My SSH agent die when Jenkins finishes processing

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have a job on Jenkins able to run a daemon (lsyncd) which persists after the end of the job. This daemon has to be run under an SSH agent so I installed a plugin for Jenkins able to set an SSH agent.

When I start my job all is OK, my lsyncd daemon is run and works correctly but once the job finished, it seems my SSH agent dies and my daemon is not able to work anymore.

Do you know how to tell Jenkins to keep my agent alive even after the job finishes?

Kind regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using something like the 'Publish over SSH' Plug-in.

You should use SSH to issue a command to spawn a new shell like `bash` instead of running the command for launching your daemon directly (not the SSH shell). Then in this bash shell run your daemon.  When it finishes, you should still have the shell active, thus the ssh agent will not terminate.

You'll need to set the timeout in the jenkins job for the SSH agent to a long timeout (or 0, which means no timeout)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you set the timeout in the jenkins job for the SSH agent? I just have a checkbox "SSH Agent", a list box to select my credentials and another checkbox "Ignore missing credentials"

Comment: @benjamin.cohen-solal  What plugin are you using to send commands to another machine over SSH?  Look into "publish over SSH", it gives lots of control over you ssh session.

Comment: I'm using "SSH Agent plugin" to set the agent from credentials and I run the shell command "ssh -A myhost mydaemon". I don't use the plugin SSH plugin because with this plugin I have to set the SSH connection in the build configuration but I want to send the credentials into the job parameters

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SSH Agent Plugin.

Comment: @benjamin.cohen-solal  Ah, I see.  You're using that plugin to store credentials to parameterize the connection--yes, I wish publish over SSH would allow you to choose the connection via parameter

Comment: Thanks Ray, but it does not work. I can successfully run my daemon (lsyncd) but this one needs the agent being configured to work properly, so the process fails with error message "permission denied". I will find another way.